How can I convert a ListContourPlot plot to a Latex contour plot?
I want my Mathematica contour plot to look as close as possible to a plot generated using LaTeX.
I am using a CSV file called unCon01new2.csv that consists of 3 columns (with no header): theta, phi, and value. This file is used to generate the contour plot you see below. I can now display both the axis labels and the frame labels in LaTeX font (thanks to Domen (see message below)), but I still have the following two problem:
1.The minimum (0.0) and maximum (1.0) values are missing in the legend bar. Does anyone know how I can include these values?
Can someone please help me fix this anomaly?

(*Load MaTeX package*)
<< MaTeX`

(*Import data*)
tupleListImport = 
  Import["path_to_file\\unCon01new2.csv"];
(*Define custom major and minor ticks lengths*)
scale = 1;
factor = scale*3.4;
majorLength = factor*0.015;
minorLength = factor*0.0075;
frameFontSize = scale*18;
labelFontMagnification = scale*1.8;
legendFontSize = scale*18;
imageSize = scale*400;
frameThickness = 0.005;

(*Define the thickness of the frame around the BarLegend*)
barLineThickness = 1.5;

(*Define custom major and minor ticks for the vertical and horizontal \
axes*)verticalMajorTicks = 
  Table[{i, 
    Style[ToString[i], FontSize -> frameFontSize], {majorLength, 
     0}}, {i, 0, 360, 45}];

verticalMinorTicks = Table[{i, "", {minorLength, 0}}, {i, 0, 360, 9}];
horizontalMajorTicks = 
  Table[{i, 
    Style[ToString[i], FontSize -> frameFontSize], {majorLength, 
     0}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}];

horizontalMinorTicks = 
  Table[{i, "", {minorLength, 0}}, {i, 0, 180, 5}];

(*Combine major and minor ticks*)
verticalTicks = Join[verticalMajorTicks, verticalMinorTicks];
horizontalTicks = Join[horizontalMajorTicks, horizontalMinorTicks];

(*Define custom ticks for the BarLegend*)
legendTicks = {0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0};

font = "Latin Modern Roman 8";

(*Generate the ListContourPlot with custom ticks and LaTeX legends*)
p2 = ListContourPlot[tupleListImport, 
   ColorFunction -> (Opacity[If[# <= 0.1, 0.0, 1.0], 
       ColorData[{"CMYKColors", "Reverse"}][#]] &), Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, 
        Magnification -> 
         labelFontMagnification] &) /@ {"\\theta\\textnormal{ [deg]}",
       "\\phi\\textnormal{ [deg]}"}, ImageSize -> imageSize, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[frameThickness], Black], 
   FrameTicks -> {horizontalTicks, verticalTicks},
   LabelStyle -> {FontSlant -> Plain, FontFamily -> font, 
     legendFontSize, Black},
   ContourStyle -> {Magenta, Dashed},
   PlotLegends -> 
    BarLegend[legendTicks, 
     LabelStyle -> {FontSlant -> Plain, FontFamily -> font, 
       legendFontSize, Black, FontSize -> legendFontSize}, 
     Method -> {Frame -> True, 
       FrameStyle -> 
        Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[barLineThickness]], 
       TicksStyle -> 
        Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[barLineThickness]]}]];
p2


Instead of "Times", you can use Latin Modern Font which is the one used in TeX, as shown in the documentation for MaTeX.

Hi Domen. Thank you for your response. Sadly, when I replace "Times" with "Latin Modern Font" I do not get latex font; it looks very different. (BTW I am using Mathematica version 12.1)

You have to download and install the font first.

Thanks Domen. I should have picked that up myself. Anyway, I did that but now I find that the tick fonts along the x-axis are far away from the plot frame. This does not happen if I use some other fonts like Times. You wouldn't happen to know how to fix this problem?

You should probably comment out your ConfigureMaTeX code. Anyone who copies and executes the code will very likely end up with a non-working MaTeX.

I got rid of ConfigureMateX. code.

I have decided to use "Latin Modern Roman 8" as a substitute for Latex font. I took a close look between this font and a latex generated font and it looks quite similar.  (I have updated both the code and the plot). However I still have the issue with the bar legend in that it is missing the 0.0 and 1.0 values. Does anyone know how I can include these values beside the bar legend? Thanks

For the BarLegend tick here is a workaround. The problem is that you have 10 colors and 11 ticks.
cols = Flatten[{White, (ColorData[{"CMYKColors", "Reverse"}] /@ 
      Subdivide[10])[[2 ;; 11]]}]    
With[{stp = 0.1}, 
      barcolrs = 
       Flatten[Table[{{(i - 1 ) stp, cols[[i]]}, {i stp, cols[[i]]}}, {i, 
          1, 11}], 1]];
    BarLegend[{Blend[barcolrs, #] &, {0, 1.1}}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 300}, Frame -> True, TicksStyle -> Black, 
     Ticks -> Table[{i + 0.05, ToString[NumberForm[i, {2, 1}]]}, {i, 0, 1,
         0.1}], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 14}]   


update
to place the ticks on the border and get the same color scheme
cols = Flatten[{White, (ColorData[{"CMYKColors", "Reverse"}] /@ 
       Subdivide[9])[[2 ;; 10]]}];
With[{stp = 0.1}, 
  barcolrs = 
   Flatten[Table[{{(i - 1) stp, cols[[i]]}, {i stp, cols[[i]]}}, {i, 
      1, 10}], 1]];
BarLegend[{Blend[barcolrs, #] &, {0, 1.0}}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 300}, Frame -> True, TicksStyle -> Black, 
 Ticks -> Table[{i, ToString[NumberForm[i, {2, 1}]]}, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}],
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 14}]

and we will get

update2:
to impose the desired ticks, we can use also Method
BarLegend[{Blend[barcolrs, #] &, {0, 1.0}}, 
 LegendMarkerSize -> {10, 300}, Frame -> True, TicksStyle -> Black, 
 Method -> {"Ticks" -> Range[0, 1, 0.1]}, 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "LM Roman 12", Black, FontSize -> 14}]     

which give the same results.

I don't think this is correct. The OP is making a contour plot, so white regions represent values smaller than 0.1, green regions values between 0.1 and 0.2 and so on ... So ticks should actually be placed on the border of two colors, not on a specific color.

just replace i + 0.05 in the Ticks with  i . I updated my answer.

You are AWESOME! Thank you, thank you, thank you, MMA13!

play with numbers inside LegendMarkerSize

I made one more small adjustment to the code: I included two variables called "barHeight" and  "barWidth", which lets a person customise the height and width of the bar legend. (See code below)
factor = scale*3.4;
majorLength = factor*0.015;
minorLength = factor*0.0075;
frameFontSize = scale*18;
labelFontMagnification = scale*1.8;
legendFontSize = scale*18;
imageSize = scale*400;
frameThickness = 0.005;

(*Define the thickness of the frame around the BarLegend*)
barLineThickness = 1.5;

(*Define custom major and minor ticks for the vertical and horizontal \
axes*)
verticalMajorTicks = 
  Table[{i, 
    Style[ToString[i], FontSize -> frameFontSize], {majorLength, 
     0}}, {i, 0, 360, 45}];
verticalMinorTicks = Table[{i, "", {minorLength, 0}}, {i, 0, 360, 9}];
horizontalMajorTicks = 
  Table[{i, 
    Style[ToString[i], FontSize -> frameFontSize], {majorLength, 
     0}}, {i, 0, 180, 30}];
horizontalMinorTicks = 
  Table[{i, "", {minorLength, 0}}, {i, 0, 180, 5}];

(*Combine major and minor ticks*)
verticalTicks = Join[verticalMajorTicks, verticalMinorTicks];
horizontalTicks = Join[horizontalMajorTicks, horizontalMinorTicks];

cols = Flatten[{White, (ColorData[{"CMYKColors", "Reverse"}] /@ 
       Subdivide[9])[[2 ;; 10]]}];

With[{stp = 0.1}, 
  barcolrs = 
   Flatten[Table[{{(i - 1) stp, cols[[i]]}, {i stp, cols[[i]]}}, {i, 
      1, 10}], 1]];

font = "Latin Modern Roman 8";

(*Define bar legend size*)
barHeight = 370;(*Adjust the height as needed*)
barWidth = 15;

(*Adjust the width as needed*)(*Generate the ListContourPlot with \
custom ticks and LaTeX legends*)
p2 = ListContourPlot[tupleListImport, 
   ColorFunction -> (Opacity[If[# <= 0.1, 0, 1.0], 
       ColorData[{"CMYKColors", "Reverse"}][#]] &), Frame -> True, 
   FrameLabel -> (MaTeX[#, 
        Magnification -> 
         labelFontMagnification] &) /@ {"\\theta\\textnormal{ [deg]}",
       "\\phi\\textnormal{ [deg]}"}, ImageSize -> imageSize, 
   InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
   FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[frameThickness], Black], 
   FrameTicks -> {horizontalTicks, verticalTicks}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSlant -> Plain, FontFamily -> font, 
     legendFontSize, Black}, ContourStyle -> {Magenta, Dashed}, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    BarLegend[{Blend[barcolrs, #] &, {0, 1.0}}, 
     LegendMarkerSize -> {barWidth, 
       barHeight},(*Custom bar legend size*)Frame -> True, 
     TicksStyle -> Black, 
     Ticks -> 
      Table[{i, ToString[NumberForm[i, {2, 1}]]}, {i, 0, 1, 0.1}], 
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
     LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> font, Black, 
       FontSize -> legendFontSize}, 
     Method -> {Frame -> True, 
       FrameStyle -> 
        Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[barLineThickness]], 
       TicksStyle -> 
        Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[barLineThickness]]}]];

p2


